# Selecting specific fields with facebook graph api

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to fetch statuses from users facebook newsfeed via the graph API.

It seems to be pretty simple when I have the right access token, then I can fetch this data with `http://graph.facebook.com/home...`  But I want to fetch only statuses; no links, photos, videos and so on..

On the documentation page, I've seen many possibilities to specify selected data, for example I can limit obtained count of posts. Is there any possibility to control which data will be particularly fetched and which not? For example like graph.facebook.com/home?type="status"..

I can classify it in my PHP script, but then I need to be able to fetch a few more posts, like when I click on the more button on facebook or twitter, etc..I see some pagination data in Facebook JSON(I hope it's JSON:)), but I am propably not capable to use it in right way..

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I believe that as far as the API is concerned, all of these are treated the same.

Answer (score 3):

The doc page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api says:

> The Graph API allows you to read properties and connections of the Facebook social graph. **You can use the API to read specific fields**, get pictures of any object, introspect an object for metadata and get real-time updates on any changes.

...and...

> You can choose the fields (or connections) you want returned with the "fields" query parameter. For example, this URL will only return the id, name, and picture of Ben: https://graph.facebook.com/bgolub?fields=id,name,picture

Comment: Yes..of course..I've written about this, but my wish is to select specific field with specific value(example: https://graph.facebook.com/bgolub?fields=type&type=status...or only https://graph.facebook.com/bgolub?type=status)..otherwise to bring pagination to work (when I filter received data in PHP, the remainder can be too small)

Comment: are you asking for pagination or searching or filtering? I can't figure out what you really want; you seem to ask about all of them. The `fields` arg lets you limit what data comes back for each record. You can search by specifying a `q` argument to the URL. If you want pagination, that's something different; use the `limit` or `since` arguments. These are all documented on the same documentation page I cited in my answer.  If you want only feeds, then send the query to the feed URL. etc.

Comment: Thanks, I am asking for something between..What I want to get exactly is STATUSES from my app user's NEWS FEED(his facebook homepage).I do not want to get LINKS, PHOTOS and so on..Simply only statuses..Imagine something like Twitter from facebook..But now I think it is not possible with graph api, but is there any way, say with FQL, how to do that?

Comment: Better say, I do not want to get "his" Statuses, but statuses od his friends, which he can see on his facebook defaut page..